# Why does Volley ImageRequest return bitmaps, and not other image file formats?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I read this [here](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-volley-to-download-cache-and-display-bitmaps.html)

> ... ImageRequest – this gets an image at a URL, returning a Bitmap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most image formats are a means to compress the image data for storage purposes.  When an image is to be drawn to the screen it needs to be a straight mapping of the pixels, with no compression/decompression involved.  That is what the bitmap format provides.. all the pixel data with no compression involved.

Comment: [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/) is a good article on bitmaps .